# How to coerce reference `&b` into `&A` for `b: B` in `let a: &A = &b;`?

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker, coercion

I have the following structs:

```
struct Age(u8);
struct User {
    age: Age,
}
```

I want to coerce a borrowed value of type `User` into an `&Age`, like in the following examples:

```
let s = String::from("abcd");
let z: &str = &s; // This works

let b = Box::new(Age(8));
let a: &Age = &b; // This also works
```

The [documentation for `Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) mentions that type `A` can be borrowed as some other type `B` if `A` implements `Borrow<B>`, so I tried to implement `Borrow<Age>` for `User`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

impl Borrow<Age> for User {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Age {
        &self.age
    }
}

fn main() {
    let u = User { age: Age(8) };
    let a: &Age = u.borrow();     // Works
    let a: &Age = &u;             // Error
}
```

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:19
   |
23 |     let a: &Age = &u; // Error: expected struct `Age`, found struct `User`
   |                   ^^ expected struct `example::Age`, found struct `example::User`
   |
   = note: expected type `&example::Age`
              found type `&example::User`
```

Am I missing something? How do I coerce `&u` into `&Age`?

Comment: This question conflates two unrelated things. Your code has essentially nothing to do with your question - whether it works or doesn't work depends on `Deref` trait, not `Borrow` trait. If you want to fix the code, you should reword the question accordingly. If you want to know about difference between `AsRef` and `Borrow`, then your code is mostly irrelevant (and there's probably a duplicate question about that already). See also: [Borrow and AsRef](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/borrow-and-asref.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I reformulated the question so that it focuses on the actual error, instead of speculating about differences between `Borrow` and `AsRef` (both traits are irrelevant for this error message). If you want to know what the difference between `Borrow` and `AsRef` is, then please ask a new question (I think it would even have good chances to become canonical). If you disagree with the edit, then please roll it back and reformulate so that your question has something to do with your code and the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two examples with `Box` and `String` work not because of the `Borrow` trait, but because of the `Deref` trait. The box `&b` in your example can be coerced into `&Age` because `Box<Age>` implements `Deref<Target = Age>`. Similarly, `String` has a `Deref` implementation so that the String reference `&s` can be coerced into `&str`. It would work for your `User` in exactly the same way:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

impl Deref for User { // That's bad, don't do that.
    type Target = Age;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Age {
        &self.age
    }
}
```

with this in scope, the following now compiles:

```
let u = User { age: Age(8) };
let a: &Age = &u;
```

Note that the example is somewhat artificial and not idiomatic: nobody would expect `User` to behave like a pointer type to `Age`. Similarly, nobody would expect that `user.borrow()` borrows `Age` instead of a `User`, that's not what the `Borrow` trait is for.